# libboost1.74-dev is not installing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boost, cmake

My current boost package is libboost-all-dev(default version 1.58.0.1) which is very old for my current need. So I tried -

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.74 libboost1.74-dev
```

It showed me error of somekind -

```
libboost1.74 is already the newest version (1.74-0~16~ubuntu16.04.1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost1.74-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,325 kB of archives.
After this operation, 139 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 393826 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost1.74-dev_1.74-0~16~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost1.74-dev (1.74-0~16~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.74-dev_1.74-0~16~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.74-dev_1.74-0~16~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However I tried several times before to manually install boost libraries. They does not seem to work though so I deleted them manually. Is this problem related to my manual deletion process? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The message makes it clear that you need to uninstall 1.58 first:

> trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/exception_ptr.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.58-dev